# Configured SSL on Apache Tomcat 7.0.47

Tags: c#, java

Have implemented SSL with self-signed certificate On Apache Tomcat  7.0.47 using Java keytool.exe.It's working fine in Browser.

Issues are:
1) while invoking the API's in java/dot net client am getting exception as "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel"

Solutions i got through online are:
1) Need to ignore invalid certificates then what's the use of SSL implementation.
2) Need to import cert into client truststore.

Could anyone suggest me how to solve this problem,is anyother ways to implement SSL and invoke those API's in client application. don't want to ignore the Cert

It's working fine in java client using InstallerCert.java class but need to invoke HTTPs API's in dot net client,any help would be really appreciated

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your Java client and your Tomcat server add `-Djavax.net.debug=all` to your command-line parameters, then post the relevant output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to establish trust relationship between client and server, in order to call server APIs. For java you can follow these steps to achieve your goal -

- Generate certificate for server (You can do this by using installCert.java)
- Once this certificate is generated usually it will be keystore file and/or .cert file
- You copy this file(s) into your JAVA_HOME/lib directory
- Then restart your server and this should be done

More info can be found from these sources - 
[security-ssl-certificate-error-use-your-trusted-certificate](http://forums.visokio.com/discussion/1365/security-ssl-certificate-error-use-your-trusted-certificate) and http://miteff.com/install-cert

Hope this helps. There are other ways also, to generate certificate but this way is easiest as per my understanding. :-)

Comment: Thanks alot,it's working fine in java client but need to invoke https API's in dot net client app.